# data replacing in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I am working in ASP.Net, I am saving the status field in Database as true or false. Now, I want to display the true or false as Active or Inactive in the front end in GridView. How to display the data in Gridview.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The alternative is to use your datagrid's RowDataBound event to convert what is it to the strings active / inactive:

```
  Protected Sub gvRequests_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvRequests.RowDataBound
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            Dim lbl As Label = CType(e.Row.FindControl("lblStatus"), Label)
            If lbl.Text="1" then
                   lbl.Text="Active"
            else
                   lbl.Text="Inactive"
            end if
        end if
  end sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to change `true` and `false` to `Active` and `Inactive`, you could use a `CASE` statement in your SQL query, like this:

```
SELECT CASE Status WHEN 1 THEN 'Active' WHEN 0 THEN 'Inactive' END FROM Something
```

For a more specific answer, please post more details.

Answer (score 0):

use checkbox column to show the status field. ( set that column to disable )

Comment: This is visually nice as it can save space however a lot of admin / assistants like to clearly see a row as inactive / active rather then remember what a check box means.  Another way to handle this is to color the row light green if it is active / light red if it is inactive.

Comment: Yes you can set the row color in databound event. That is more userfriendly. (i.e Green-Active, Red-InActive

Answer (score 0):

If you know the cell location of which you want to filter data, you could also do this in the gridviews RowDataBound event.

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (e.Row.Cells[2].Text == "1")
                e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "True";
            else
                e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "False";
        }
    }
```

This is what I used to find and replace text in a gridview.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using template field then you can create server side function and call on Eval like below

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblstatus" runat="server" Text='<%# GetStatusText(Eval("status")) %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>




public string GetStatusText(string strIsActive)
        {
          bool val = Boolean.Parse(strIsActive);
          if(val)
          { 
             return "Active";
          }
          else
          { 
             return "Inactive";
          }
        }
```